# AttributeError: 'VideoObjectDetection' object has no attribute 'detectObjectsFromImage'

Tags: python, opencv, imageai

Try to create object detection program using ImageAI.There is detectObjectsFromImage command on ImageAI documentation but when i try to use this

```
AttributeError: 'VideoObjectDetection' object has no attribute 'detectObjectsFromImage'
```

Code:

```
    from imageai.Detection import VideoObjectDetection
UAVImages = os.listdir("UAV")
randomFile = UAVImages[random.randint(0, len(UAVImages) - 1)]

detectedImage, detections = detector.detectObjectsFromImage(output_type="array", input_image="UAV/{0}".format(randomFile), minimum_percentage_probability=30)
convertedImage = cv.cvtColor(detectedImage, cv.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
showImage(convertedImage)

for eachObject in detections:
    print(eachObject["name"] , " : ", eachObject["percentage_probability"], " : ", eachObject["box_points"] )
    print("--------------------------------")
```